# MongoDB - Get Data from startDate to endDate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

So, I have JSON like this in DB ( I use mongoDB )

```
{ 
    "uSN": "100030001",
    "timestamp": 1470009600,
    "timetag": 1082016,
    "monthtag": 82016,
    "hourtag": 11,
    "mintag": 10,
    "yeartag": 2016, 
    "id": "d100030001_01082016_11_10"
  },
  { 
    "uSN": "100030001",
    "timestamp": 1470096000,
    "timetag": 2082016,
    "monthtag": 82016,
    "hourtag": 11,
    "mintag": 10,
    "yeartag": 2016, 
    "id": "d100030001_02082016_11_10"
  },
  { 
    "uSN": "100030001",
    "timestamp": 1469850900,
    "timetag": 30072016,
    "monthtag": 72016,
    "hourtag": 10,
    "mintag": 55,
    "yeartag": 2016, 
    "id": "d100030001_30072016_10_55"
  },
  { 
    "uSN": "100030001",
    "timestamp": 1469923200,
    "timetag": 31072016,
    "monthtag": 72016,
    "hourtag": 11,
    "mintag": 10,
    "yeartag": 2016, 
    "id": "d100030001_31072016_11_10"
  },
  { 
    "uSN": "100030001",
    "timestamp": 1469577600,
    "timetag": 27072016,
    "monthtag": 72016,
    "hourtag": 11,
    "mintag": 10,
    "yeartag": 2016, 
    "id": "d100030001_27072016_11_10"
  }
```

I'm trying to do query from my mongo shell to get Data from 30-07-2016 until 01-08-2016. 
I'm using this:
 
`db.dataProfTable.find({ uSN: '100030001', timestamp : {'$gte': new Date(1469836800), '$lte': new Date(1470009600)})`
and
 `db.dataProfTable.find({'uSN': '100030001', 'timetag': {$gte: '30072016', $lt: '01082016'}})`

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) on `$and` operation and use it for `$gte` and `$lte`.

Comment: What is the Mongo data type of timestamp and timetag? Is that actually timestamp or just double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the input as the date range "30-07-2016" to "01-08-2016", construct some JS dates to use in your query. Get the timestamps in seconds (as the document schema implies) from the dates by dividing by 1000:

```
var start = new Date("2016-07-30")/1000,
    end = new Date("2016-08-01")/1000;
db.dataProfTable.find({
    "timestamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
})
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579f04ccd8f31a5788eba0fb"),
    "uSN" : "100030001",
    "timestamp" : 1470009600,
    "timetag" : 1082016,
    "monthtag" : 82016,
    "hourtag" : 11,
    "mintag" : 10,
    "yeartag" : 2016,
    "id" : "d100030001_01082016_11_10"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579f04ccd8f31a5788eba0fd"),
    "uSN" : "100030001",
    "timestamp" : 1469850900,
    "timetag" : 30072016,
    "monthtag" : 72016,
    "hourtag" : 10,
    "mintag" : 55,
    "yeartag" : 2016,
    "id" : "d100030001_30072016_10_55"
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried this and tweaks it a bit in my NodeJS app and works like a charm. Thank you mate!!

Answer (score 2):

```
     Try This !!!
```

For,

1.**Monthtag** :

> db.dataProfTable.find({ uSN: '100030001', $and:[ {monthtag : {$gte:
>   72016}},{monthtag : {$lte: 82016}}]})

2.**Timestamp** :

> db.dataProfTable.find({ uSN: '100030001', $and:[ {timestamp : {$gte:
>   1469836800}},{timestamp : {$lte: 1470009600}}]})

Answer (score 1):

To query by timestamp use below:

```
var start = new Date("07/30/2016").getTime()/1000 //Date Format:mm/dd/yyyy. Doing by 1000 since u stored in seconds
var end = new Date("08/01/2016").getTime()/1000
db.dataProfTable.find({ uSN: '100030001', $and:[ {timestamp : {$gte:start}},{timestamp : {$lte: end}}]})
```

To query by timetag use below:

```
db.dataProfTable.find({'uSN': '100030001', 'timetag': {$gte: 30072016, $lt: 01082016}}) // Since u stored as number for timetag
```